# new lines in a text within a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a little confused due to when I insert a text stored in mysql in a div I use the following sentence to insert the text:

```
<div class="menssge_holder"><?php echo str_replace("\n", "</p>", $conversation[$i]['message']); ?></div>
```

That sentence works fine, but when the user enter a new message in a textarea and press send button, i put that text within the div_holder and '\n' do not take effect.

What's the equivalent I should use in javascript or jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: try `"\r\n"` instead. not everyone uses just newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="menssge_holder"><?php echo str_replace(/\n/ig, "<br />", $conversation[$i]['message']); ?></div>
```

In your case you need something like this:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ayizof/4/edit)*

```
$('#post').click(function(){
  
  var copyThis = $('#textarea').val().replace(/\n/ig, '<br />');  
  $('#result').html( copyThis );
  
});
```

Comment: In php works, i meant in javascript, inserting a text from a textarea into a div.

Comment: @domoindal added what you need, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate incorrect html. You will have a bunch of `</p>` with no `<p>` if you want to replace `\n` with a new line, try `<br />` instead of `</p>.` As suggested above my @MarcB you may also want to try replacing `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `</p>` with `<p>` or `<br />` and it would work. Also, if you are using `p`, giving CSS to `p` this way will be helpful:

```
p {margin: 0 0 15px;}
```

Comment: He would still lack </p> tags if he replaces \n by <p>

Comment: @Korcholis, that won't be a problem in almost all the browsers. a `<p>` tag cannot be contained inside another `<p>` tag. So, no worries. :) The browser implicitly puts `</p>`. Check out Firebug's source code with something like `<p>Hi<p>Hello<p>How`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. However, I don't know how IE behaves in this case. Yes, I (sadly) have to keep an eye on past :(

Comment: Well, this is totally surprising. +1 to you @Praveen Kumar, and probably +1 to Microsoft, if they did this on purpose =)

Comment: However, it's a matter of the browser developer to implement all the w3c rules. In this case, so, Microsoft did a good job and stuck to standards.